# How to configure underlying JSON serialization options for Azure SignalR Management library?

Tags: signalr-hub, azure-signalr

I'm trying to figure out how to configure the JSON serialization settings that the Azure SignalR Management library uses. How can I specify that the JSON should be serialized with camelCase property names instead of UpperCase names?

Here's a bit of code that sends a message ...

```
private static IServiceManager CreateServiceManager(string connectionString)
{
    var builder = new ServiceManagerBuilder()
        .WithOptions(options => { options.ConnectionString = connectionString; });

    return builder.Build();
}

public static async Task SendLogMessageAsync(string connectionString, string userId, LogMessage logMessage)
{
    using (var manager = CreateServiceManager(connectionString))
    {
        var hubContext = await manager.CreateHubContextAsync("SystemEventHub");

        await hubContext.Clients.User(userId).SendCoreAsync("ReceiveLogMessage", new[] { logMessage });

        await hubContext.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

You can see that I'm providing a `LogMessage` instance as the message parameter. The `SendCoreAsync` method is serializing it using UpperCase property names. I'd like that to be configured to send using camelCase properties.

This is using the `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management` nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response provided a hint to what the problem, but in the example code he is using the CreateServiceManager and CreateHubContextAsync, which I am using too, and there's no builder in my startup classes because this isn't in an Azure Function. I'm wanting my C# .Net Core API to use the Azure SignalR in Serverless mode, and here's what got it to work for me. Adding the .WIthOptions section as below, updated the message publisher/sender to serialize in camel case, which it didn't by default:

```
            using var serviceManager = new ServiceManagerBuilder()
            .WithConfiguration(_configuration)
            .WithOptions(o => o.UseJsonObjectSerializer(new JsonObjectSerializer(
                new JsonSerializerOptions()
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                })))
            .WithLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory)
            .BuildServiceManager();

        _hubContext = await serviceManager.CreateHubContextAsync(_hubName, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can :-)  It took a lot of looking around to find this and I came across a lot of suggested solutions (that didn't work) before finally getting to this solution.

If you're using the System.Text.Json serializer use this in your configure method in the startup class.

```
builder.Services.Configure<SignalROptions>(o => o.JsonObjectSerializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(
new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
}));
```

If you're using Newtonsoft use this instead

```
builder.Services.Configure<SignalROptions>(o => o.JsonObjectSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer(
new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
}));
```

This is the article i got the solution from [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/signalr/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService/samples/Sample02_CustomizingJsonSerialization.md)